# SQL Syntax for grouping by week-interval with certain date range

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, mariadb

Suppose I have a dataset like this:

```
value   |   date
9       | 2016-06-02
2       | 2016-06-07
```

I have a query like :

```
SELECT SUM(`value`) AS `value`,  CONCAT(date, ' - ', date + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS `date`
FROM test
GROUP BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,DATE('2016-05-28'),DATE('2016-06-08'))
```

And hope it would be like this :

```
value   |   date
9       | 2016-05-28 - 2016-06-03
2       | 2016-06-04 - 2016-06-08
```

What am I missing?
nb: The date in group by is user generated, and I know the `select concat...` syntax is kinda wrong too, because it produces a different result that I want to get

Comment: What is the logic to get  `2016-05-28 - 2016-05-03` and `2016-06-04 - 2016-06-08`

Comment: it's split by 7 days interval, and oh yeah, I've already changed the expected result @Utsav

Comment: Where does `2016-06-02` it in?  What is the significance of `9`?